# Laravel dependency injection with base class

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection, eloquent, laravel-5.5

I'm relatively new to Laravel and I have created a middleware and policy to handle 'Ownable' Eloquent objects in my project.

I did this using a trait:

```
trait Ownable
{

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'created_by');
    }
}
```

In my policy I simply do this:

```
class RightPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    public function update(User $user, Ownable $ownable)
    {
        return $ownable->created_by == $user->id;
    }
}
```

And my middleware, assigned to the correct action in my controller:

```
class CheckRights
{
    public function __construct(Route $route, Ownable $object) {
        $this->route = $route;
        $this->object = $object;
    }

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
         // @TODO handle request
    }
}
```

Then I created a class using the Ownable trait:

```
class Thread extends Model
{
    use Ownable;
}
```

However, when I try to run the project with this structure, Laravel's dependency injector trhows an error:

> Target [App\Ownable] is not instantiable while building App\Http\Middleware\CheckRights

Is there a way to let the dependency injector know to instantiate the right class (maybe using the routes or something else)?

If not, is there a handy way to do something else without the dependency injector to make sure the correct class is instantiated?

Comment: A trait is not instantiable by definition. I don't think you need trait here, it's more about Class and Extends

Comment: I understand that, I am using traits here for polymorphic reasons. A thread is Ownable, but is also Commentable, however, a ForumRule, is not Ownable, but is Commentable (for example). That is why I chose for this type of structure. @VincentDecaux

Comment: Result of using a Trait can always be written out as a valid class in its own right. When Laravel applies automatic resolution in that trait, it tries to init which does not work. So your way would be to switch to a class instead of using a trait here if you want to go to the point you want.

Comment: how would the middleware know what input to check on the request for the assumed bound model to check? Not sure why you need anything in the constructor of that middleware as the request itself will have access to what you need to check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by using the app::bind method in the AppServiceProvider.

In the register method of the service provider I bound a App\Ownable inteface to a function which loops trough all injected Eloquent objects which are passed to the router.

```
namespace App\Providers;

use App\Ownable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
    }

    public function register()
    {
        // Binding ownable trait/interface for correctly handling policy
        $this->app->bind('App\Ownable', function() {
            // Get all parameters passed to the current route
            $array = Route::getCurrentRoute()->parameters;

            $return = NULL;
            foreach ($array as $object){
                if ($object instanceof Ownable){
                    // Fetch the last ownable instance found passed to the route
                    $return = $object;
                }
            }

            // return it
            return $return;
        });
    }
}
```

Read more about: [Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/container#binding)

Then I combined the Ownable trait with an interface for correct typehinting, as suggested on a forum on an other website:

```
class Thread extends Model implements \App\Interfaces\Ownable
{
    use Ownable;
}
```

Then in my middleware constructor I made the ownable parameter optional (for when the store or create action is called and no object is given) and handled my request based on the action name and if an object is given

```
class CheckRights
{
    public function __construct(Route $route, Ownable $object = null) {
        $this->route = $route;
        $this->object = $object;
    }

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        // Get the controller's action name
        $action = $this->route->getActionName();
        $action = substr($action, strpos($action, '@') + 1);

        // Check if an object is given in the request
        if ($action != 'store' && $action != 'create' && isset($this->object)){
            // Check if gate allows user to update/delete object
            if ($request->user()->can($action, $this->object)){
                return $next($request);
            }
        }elseif($action == 'store' || $action == 'create'){
            // Check if gate allows user to create object
            if ($request->user()->can($action, Ownable::class)){
                return $next($request);
            }
        }

        return back();
    }
}
```